# Wamp and xampp on same machine

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp

I use wamp2.2 for all the time, but i had to install xamp1.6.8 cause i've got to work with project created for old php version. Xamp installation goes fine but when i run it i cant get localhost site. Ive got blank page with favicon of wamp and comunicate that site is unavaible. I know that this is configuration case. Anybody know how to fix this?

I want to run only one of them at once, and i have configured some virtualhosts for wamp they dont have to be accesible while xamp is running i need xamp only for one project.

Answer (score 9):

for run xampp and wamp in same computer you can use this tutorial from arasjoomla website: http://arasjoomla.ir/joomla-tutorial/how-to-run-xampp-and-wamp-on-same-computer
for example we used wamp with default port and setting and set changed in xampp:

1. Change xampp apache port 80 to example 8080 in `httpd.conf` from
   directory `C:\xampp\apache\conf`
2. In `my.ini` from `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` change `port=3306` to `port=3307`
3. In `config.inc.php` from `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin` after this code:

   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

   add this code:

   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';`
4. restart xampp now we cab use xampp and wamp for example use this
   code in xampp `port 3307` for connection database:

   ```
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "my_db";
   $port = '3307';

   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname,$port);
   if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
      }
    } else 
        echo "0 results";

   mysqli_close($conn);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

WAMP and XAMPP are basically the same thing i.e. Apache MySQL and PHP so if one is running it's Apache will have captured port 80, so the second one wont be able to get to port 80, ditto one's MySQL server will have captured port 3306 so the others wont run.

Why do you need to install XAMPP to get an old version of PHP running, WAMPServer is designed to allow you to switch between multiple versions of Apache/MySQL and PHP fairly easily.

But now you have done it, just make sure that the Apache and MySQL services from XAMPP are set to start manually and also Wampservers [wampapache] and [wampmysqld] services as well. then just run only one of them at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

I have two working together, first was wamp. So xampp has to be changed at:

```
httpd.conf : 
    Listen 8080
    ServerName localhost:8080

httpd-ssl.conf : 
    Listen 4433
    <VirtualHost _default_:4433>www.example.com:4433
```

By the way, I realised so xampp has much better, mean faster, refreshing time.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that they are both trying to run on the same port via localhost.
I think it will be difficult to run both at the same time, there's a much better way to this using a tool called "Vagrant".

Vagrant allows you to start up a virtual host that you have full control over, including PHP version. You can see more information about Vagrant at http://www.vagrantup.com/. This tutorial is what helped me get set up and understand how it works: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/vagrant-what-why-and-how--net-26500.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run both XAMPP and WAMP together on the same machine but access only one of the servers at a time then you could go ahead installing both of them one after another. But, keep in mind that before installing the other server you have to completely stop all the services running from the XAMPP or WAMP control panel then quit the application. After this step you can go ahead installing the other server without changing any configurations or port numbers. This is because in this case we assumed that only one of the servers would be accessed at a time. Hence, before launching the other server one has to completely quit the application that is running currently by stopping all of it's services. If skype is installed then one has to change the default incoming connection ports to other than port 80 and 443.

If you messed up changing ports and config files then you could end up with the following error while trying to access phpmyadmin from XAMPP control panel:

```
    **mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings. xampp**
```

**note:** *while launching the servers ,* **run it as administrator** *else some services will not start properly.*

> I TRIED INSTALLING BOTH XAMPP AND WAMP ON WINDOWS 10 AS SUCH AS
>   POINTED BY MANY THREADS I CHANGED THE DEFAULT PORTS FOR MYSQL & APACHE
>   XAMPP AS IT WOULD CONFLICT WITH WAMP ALREADY INSTALLED ONLY ENDING UP
>   UNABLE TO ACCESS PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. THEN REINSTALLED
>   XAMPP WITHOUT CHANGING ANY CONFIGS OR PORTS. STOP THE WAMP SERVICES,
>   QUIT THE APP AND THEN LAUNCH PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. AT
>   LAST IT WORKED!. THE PROCESS LOOKS SHORT THOUGH WHEN IN REALITY IT
>   TOOK ME COUNTLESS HOURS AND PAIN RESEARCHING ON THE WEB AND TESTING
>   FOR A POSSIBLE SOLUTION UNTILL I CAME UP WITH THIS.

Hopes, this quick tips and guides would be helpful.

Comment: If you are citing some source please add a reference to it's origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys wanna use MYSQL specifically on Both Wamp and Xampp . Yes It's possible. Not only that You can use the Apache server and all the components of it parallely. Let's say you need two different versions of MYSQL on a same machine then this solution that I am gonna tell you will be helpful.

First Install WAMP server and then after launching it Just go down to the bottom right of ur desktop and hit on the wamp server icon. You will be able to see All the components there. Now if you hit on MYSQL specifically then you'll see a my.ini file pointed there. Now open that file on a notepad and then search for "port" and replace the existing port of mysql which is 3306 to a new random port let's say 3360.
Now after this just press on restart all the services It's done.

Now Install xampp server and now go to xamp folder and search for mysql and rename that to mysql_old. Create a new and empty mysql folder now. Now redirect to the below link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html?os=3&version=5  and download the zip and extract it. After extracting it just paste all the contents of it in the newly created mysql folder. Now redirect to the bin path inside newly created mysql folder and create a new my.ini file. Over there just paste the below contents:

```
[mysqld]
# Set basedir to your installation path
basedir=C:/xampp/mysql
port=3306
key_buffer_size = 256M

# Set datadir to the location of your data directory
datadir=C:/xampp/mysql/data

# Default: 128 MB
# New: 1024 MB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M

# Default since MySQL 8: caching_sha2_password
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

[client]
ssl-mode=DISABLED
port=3306 #This port can be again anything..
```

Now after this just redirect to bin folder and hit on mysql d --initialize.
And then you're good to run mysql server on xamp using the following command
mysql -u root -p -h localhost.
This can help u run mysql on a different port.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both at the same time, try to use different ports for each software bundle like others said.
And in this case u need to specify your port in the php file as well.

Additionally, for those who are new to that software,

You can have both wamp and Xampp on same machine.

- wamp for windows
- lamp for linux
- mamp for mac
- xampp for cross platform

So, when your machine has both software try to use a software at a time, not having both run on same time.

If any of that software give any error. Try to stop relevant other software's services first and try again. (use "Services" in task manager or cmd to do that)

Thank you.