# Run XAMPP folder in WAMP server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xampp, localhost, wamp

I have my folder run on XAMPP Server and when i turn off Xampp server And restart all service in WAMP server and when i try to run the same folder in WAMP no data is read

is there any port need to change or somthing?

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639237/wamp-and-xampp-on-same-machine. Check that answers.

Comment: I have an ideas what you are trying to do but it would be good if you clarified it more precisely please.

Comment: Do you have a Virtual Host defined in WAMPServer so it knows to look for your site in the XAMPP folders? This questions assumes I have read correctly read between the lines of your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can i know if i have virtual host?

Comment: If you dont know, you dont have them

Comment: I am really not sure what you are trying to ask. Please have another go at explaining what you are trying to do here

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have folder of phps files , i locate the folder in xampp/htdoc and my project read the data from database perfectly , then i power  off xampp and start all services in wamp then i locate the same folder in wamp/www but there is not data read from the database , and i want to know why the folder run in xampp server rather than wamp

Comment: So you want WAMPServer to use the XAMPP `htdocs` folder as the DocumentRoot?

Comment: Exactly as the docRoot

Comment: What about the databases? WAMPServer and XAMPP both have a MySQL server database if yo loaded the XAMPP database the WAMPServer database will be empty.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have import it successfully and its work right now , thank you mr riggsFolly can i take the chance to look at my question here stackoverflow.com/questions/43496049/… – RAB 13 hours ago   delete